# Elasticsearch indexing problem after upgrading to 2.4.4-p1

Tags: reindex, elasticsearch, magento2.4.4

after upgrading Magento C.E to version 2.4.4-P1
I found out that I keep getting this error message when I reindex catalog search:

```
Catalog Search index process error during indexation process:
429 Too Many Requests /magento2_product_4_v18022/document/_bulk
```

its elastic search problem, we are using AWS
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in AWS elasticsearch plan
we had t2.medium.search, its no longer satisfying Magento needs.
now its working after upgrading i3.large.search